# Compiling Lua 5.2 In Freeswitch 1.7

Tags: lua, voip, freeswitch

When making from git source the Lua module fails complaining about a missing lua.h file.

I see the file is there in /usr/src/freeswitch/src/mod/languages/mod_lua/lua which I had rather assumed was FS's own 5.2 version.

My OS has Lua 5.1 preinstalled and when I installed the -devel package the compilation completed and Lua seems to run fine within FS. Running a test file with

```
freeswitch.consoleLog("err","Lua Version : "..tostring(_VERSION))
```

from the FS CLI shows FS is using 5.1. I'd like to get onto 5.2 as that seems to be the official supported version.

*EDIT - discovered why this is - I added --enable-system-lua to configure, just for something to try. That explains why it compiled to the OS installed Lua. But if I remove that the compile to 5.2 still fails with that missing lua.h file even though it appears to be in the src.*

So my question(s) -

1. does FS bring its own Lua 5.2 source to compile? If so, how do I get it to use it?
2. if not 1, do I have to remove the 5.1 version and install 5.2 from the Lua site and re-make?

Any other tips would be handy. Google doesn't show this particular problem (that I can find).

**Freeswitch version :**
FreeSWITCH Version 1.7.0+git~20150821T015758Z~d262f07d0f~64bit (git d262f07 2015-08-21 01:57:58Z 64bit)

**CentOS version** : 6.7

Comment: what is the output of this `lua ~stream:write("1234#5678")` command in cli ? Do you see lua command in cli or not ?

Comment: It outputs "1234#5678" - not sure I understand what that's supposed to do?

Comment: Do you have installed lua 5.2 and its devel package in your system ? if not please install it either using yum/rpm/source (no need to remove lua 5.2).